# ITMS-90809:Deprecated API Usage-Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView API

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, app-store

I saw some other questions with same title, but my question is different.

Yesterday, I uploaded my App to TestFlight and after a while, Apple sent me this warning:

**ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.**

I am using `WebView` for showing HTML data in my app. Also, I have used `WebView` for playing audio and video. So is this warning reject my app when submitting for review or should I change these features with some other APIs?

In this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) provided by AppStore, telling about use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`, I tried that and no such property found on XAML. Should I need to install any packages for getting that feature? Also, by using `WKWebView`, is it possible to play audio, video and showing HTML data in the app?

**Update 1**

Getting `System.ArumentNullException` when work with the custom renderer. Am I missing something?

[image]

**Update 2: Renderer Codes**
**PCL**

```
public class MyWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Url",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The custom renderer for this class on iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace WKWebViewDemo.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView _wkWebView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Url)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:MyWebView Url="https://www.microsoft.com" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I create a new project and add your codes there, it works on my side. Is there any other codes in your project?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT No other codes added, can you share a sample?

Comment: You can check the sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Usage-of-WKWebview), let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I tested your sample code, it is working fine. I have used exactly the same code on my project, but showing the exception. I am using the XF version: 4.3.0.778476-pre1, is there any other reason for this exception?

Comment: I test my sample under 4.3.0.778476-pre1 and it also works. I can check it for you if can share me your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This issue has been solved and the solution can be found in the below answer

[ITMS-90909: Deprecated API Usage with iOS in Xamarin Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136458/itms-90909-deprecated-api-usage-with-ios-in-xamarin-forms-app/60136621#60136621)

This is an open bug with Xamarin.Forms at [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7323)

As of now, I do not see any workaround or something on the thread but you can wait for it to be fixed with the next releases of `Xamarin.Forms`

**Update**: saw a workaround which might work check this out https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7323#issuecomment-527294907

Comment: Is this work?
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129626/how-does-one-implement-wkwebview-ios-in-a-cross-platform-application

Comment: Ideally, this should work, Go ahead and give it a run. Also if you have latest XF I guess you have `WKWebViewRenderer`  readly available. I am not sure though

Comment: I will do a push to test flight with this and give you an update, thanks.

Comment: I edited the question with a screenshot, can you please have a look?

Comment: Are you sure control in the second if condition, will never be null?

Comment: I commented the second if, now no exception showing, but webview is not showing in UI.

Comment: I didn't get you